# Why don't some packages move into vendor folder in angular 2 install

Tags: node.js, angular

I've just set up a basic project in angular 2 using their cli. When i do a node install --save for a material design project the files are in node_modules and dist/vendor. However when i install angular2-localstorage there is just a folder in node_modules which is not web accessible.

Following some stuff online the suggestion for my mapping is

```
const map: any = {
    '@angular2-material':         'vendor/@angular2-material',
    'angular2-localstorage':      'node_modules/angular2-localstorage'
};
```

This produces 404 for my localstorage and material works fine.

Am I missing something? How do I get the local storage to work.

Furthermore. the local storage folder in node_modules only has a ts file and not a js file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably forgot to add them to the list of vendor files, see guide: [3rd party lib installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs#2-add-momentjs-to-angular-cli-buildjs-file-to-vendornpmfiles-array)

```
//angular-cli.build.js
module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      // ...
      '@angular2-material/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
      'angular2-localstorage/**/*.+(js|js.map)'
    ]
  });
};
```

Comment: The localstorage installed into node_modules only has an index.js and the actual library files are ts. Is there some sort of flag I can set to also convert it to javascript?